# Most Versatile Light Modifier for Portrait/Glamour/Fashion

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting, diffusers

I recently got a Godox V860C flash and a Godox Cells II trigger.

Now, I want to do a bit of portrait / glamour / fashion photography -- and I need recommendations on a light modifier. I got the trigger because I want to shoot with the light off camera (but not absolutely necessary). To shoot off camera, I was thinking of getting something like http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_S_type_Speedlite_Bracket.html.

I know the answer to my question is going to be very subjective, but here it is: **what is the most versatile light diffuser to have with one speedlight and shooting for portrait / glamour / fashion?** Portability would be a bonus. Shooting will be done indoors and outdoors.

Should I just get a big umbrella (shoot through/bounce)? A softbox? Or forget shooting off camera and just get something like Gary Fong's Lightsphere?

Comment: Um. It's not really about versatility so much as what kind of light you want. That's why there are so many different types of modifiers. You're gonna end up with more than one. See: http://zackarias.com/for-photographers/creativelive/modifiers-from-day-03-of-my-creativelive-class/

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a shoot through umbrella that also can be used with a cover as an umbrella to reflect the light to be the most versatile.

For portraits you can do a lot with an umbrella and a bare flash, of course you'll need to flash units for that.

On camera I wouldn't waste your money on a Fong Bong, just make sure your flash can rotate properly and utilize your surroundings to bounce when on the move or you don't have the option for an umbrella/box.

If fashion is important to you but you don't have the budget for additional equipment, you could create a DIY ring flash for a few dollars. Lots of tutorials exist online for this.